# Screen reader does not read the listbox options in firefox

Tags: html, reactjs, accessibility

I have simple autosuggest that displays the suggestions on the basis of user input.

But screen reader does not read the option value when tabbed or arrow keys are used.

Here is the sample code:

```
<div id="autosuggest" role="listbox">
   <div id="autosuggest_list">
      <button role="link">Value1</button>
      <button role="link">Value2</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: I don't have access to screen reader so sorry for my poor testing. Have you try to make `autosuggest_list` as a proper list using `ul` tag? And the option as a list as in `li` tag? Or use `select` with `option`.

Also I don't think the `button` need `role="link"`, if you need a link use anchor tag instead.

Comment: Use `role="option"` for the option elements inside `role="listbox"` element. You should use `ul` and `li` combination and screen reader will speak e.g. `<name> 1 of 10` when you navigate using arrow keys.